# Configurar x509 en Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Necesito un poco de consejo con una aplicación que estamos desarrollando mi equipo y yo.

La cuestión es que se nos ha pedido crear una aplicación a la cual se pueda acceder mediante PKI. Nos han dado los .cer y el .key para validar, y un nginx configurado (es de otra aplicación e imagino que tendría que configurarlo para la nuestra).

El problema con esto es que no tengo ni idea de nada de esto, pero me ha tocado el marrón a mi. Se lo básico de mutual authentification, pero tan básico como que el agua moja. Los tutoriales que he mirado son para logearte mediante user y pass, y como digo tampoco manejo el entorno de spring, así que el tema de las anotaciones y tal voy mal.

Comment: Básicamente, tu pregunta es: ¿cómo aseguro mi servicio con un certificado de seguridad x509 que debo generar para los clientes usando Spring MVC?

Comment: Empleando ademas una tarjeta PKI, que bueno, imagino que sabiendo lo primero el resto va rodado.